# Padding Conundrum

Tags: html, css, wrapper, margin, padding

I can't figure out this padding. I'd like to get rid of the subtle top and left padding around the photo on my home page, claireisabelwebb.com.

Here is my css:

```
/* Wrapper for Text and Photo on Home Page */

.wrapper_text_photo{ 
        display:block;
        /* float: left; */
        position: fixed;;
        background: rgba(0,0,255, 0);
        height: 800px;
        padding-top: 3px;
        padding-left: 10 px;
        margin-top:20px;
        /* margin-left:100px;*/
        margin-left:55px;
        /* margin-left:100px;*/
        margin-top: 232px;
}

/* Photo on Home Page */

.photo_home {
        float: left;
        margin-right:10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        background: rgba(0,0,255, 0);
}

/* Text on Home Page */

.home_text{ 
        display:block;
        position: fixed;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.85);
        width:1100px;
        height: 480px;
        margin-left: 300px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 5px;

}
.home_text p img {
    float:left;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, .85);
}
```

And html:

```
    <!-- Text and Photo __________________________________________-->

<div class="wrapper_text_photo">

    <div class="home_text">
            <p><img class="photo_home" src="http://claireisabelwebb.com/images/Home/claire-ed.jpg" alt="person_name" height="280px" />I graduated in YYYY from XXXX College with departmental honors in SUBJECT. As a junior, I participated in a XXXX mission in PLACE. <br><br>
            Email me at someemail@someemail.com.
            <br> 
            &raquo;try scrolling this page up and down&laquo;
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's hard for me to see where the margins and padding are for the wrapper, and how this interacts with each element's (photo and text box) padding and margin. Is this the correct method of coding this?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.photo_home {
    ...
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    ...
}
```

This wouldn't happen to have anything to do with it, would it? Try removing the padding lines there.

Comment: You always beat me to the answer by 30 seconds. ;)

Comment: People call me The Sniper on several sites and chatrooms I'm in :p

Comment: thank you, i tried that before. that is fine, but i'd like the have the spacing of that padding. i just don't get why it's white, not transparent.

Comment: Try using `margin` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding padding. If you don't want the padding to show a background, you have two options.

Switch it to margin:

```
.photo_home {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
}
```

or use this style for background transparency:

```
.photo_home {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

[image]